# Click not firing on css animated element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a little green bar `contactPull` absolutely positioned to the right of a div `box-left`. I wish to toggle `box-left` class when `contactPull` is being clicked. To do so, I attach the code as is. Nothing happens when I click `contactPull`, and the console log is not printed. I tried to to the same with several other elements and it works very well. **I don't understand why only `contactPull` won't answer my click event.**

*The script is at the end and this is probably where I have something wrong. You can have a look at the UI after the script.*

**EDIT:** I think my animation is causing the JQuery not to be toggled. It seems JQuery gets called only after the css animation starts. Correct me if I am wrong. See CSS for the update.

CSS:

```
.arrowRight {
  margin-top: 175px;
  width: 0; 
  height: 0; 
  margin-left: -10px;
  border-top:     15px solid transparent;
  border-bottom:  15px solid transparent;
  border-right:   15px solid #D1F486;
}
.box-left {
  float: left;
  width: 440px;
  height: 352px;
  border-right:   solid 1px #D1F486;
  border-top:     solid 1px #D1F486;
  border-bottom:  solid 1px #D1F486;
  border-left:    solid 4px #D1F486;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: whitesmoke;
  color: gray;
}
.contactPull {
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: 460px;
  float: right;
  height: 373px;
  width: 5px;
  background-color: #D1F486;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.contactPull:active + .box-left {
  width: 0;
  opacity: 0;
}
.contactPull:active {
  margin-left: 0;
}
.contactPull:active .arrowRight{
  border-left:   15px solid #D1F486;
  border-right: none;
  margin-left: 0;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="contactPull"><div class="arrowRight"></div></div>
<div class="shown box-left">
    <!-- some unimportant stuff -->
</div>
```

JS:

```
$(function () 
{
    $('.contactPull').click(function(e) 
    {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('.box-left').toggleClass("shown hidden");
        console.log("this is the click");
    });
});
```

[image]

Comment: Works fine - http://jsfiddle.net/Hn5Yn/.

Comment: Tip - Use the developer console, then you'll see the obvious mistake(s)

Comment: Also, as a side note your English would be better as `Please point out your goals, deadlines and budget. I'll get back to you within 24 hours with my availability and we can then discuss the details.`

Comment: Thanks, english is not my first language and this insight is appreciated ;)

Comment: @null Works on the fiddle, will probably look and see what differs from it in my code, but I doubt any major changes will be found.

Answer (score 2):

You haven't closed the ready function...

```
$(function () {
  $('.contactPull').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.box-left').toggleClass("shown hidden");
    console.log("this is the click");
  });
}); <--- missing
```

Comment: @Francis.Beauchamp then the code is working fine... http://jsfiddle.net/tilwinjoy/SMqu5/

Answer (score 0):

I ended up replacing the `:active` CSS selector with a new `.active` class like so:

CSS:

```
.contactPull.active + .box-left {
  width: 0;
  opacity: 0;
}
.contactPull.active {
  margin-left: 0;
}
.contactPull.active .arrowRight{
  border-left:   15px solid #D1F486;
  border-right: none;
  margin-left: 0;
}
```

JS:

```
$(function () {
    $('.contactPull').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(".contactPull").toggleClass("shown active");
        console.log("this is the click");
    });
});
```